# on tap rehaga una consulta a un servicio

Tags: api, flutter, dart, rest

estoy con un proyecto en el que tengo un listado de clientes, y quiero que cada vez que hago click en uno de ellos me navegue a otra pagina en la que me muestra los datos del cliente. Tal y como han hecho el api rest, los datos del cliente me los trae pero poniendo en el body lo siguiente

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <SociedadOtros_Lee xmlns="http://xxxxxx/">
      <usuario>xxxxx</usuario>
      <password>xxxxxx</password>
      <Codigo>112</Codigo>
    </SociedadOtros_Lee>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

el problema lo tengo que el codigo me lo da cuando hago click en el cliente, llama al servicio y me trae los datos, pero cuando vuelvo atras y hago click en otro cliente no vuelve a pasar por el servicio sino que me trae lo que ya habia antes.

Mi duda es:
1.- como paso el codigo del cliente al servicio para ponerlo en el codigo del body
2.- como puedo hacer para que cada vez que hago click en un cliente vuelva a llamar al servicio.
Gracias

Edito mi pregunta como me comentan

Este es el codigo de la pagina de datos del cliente

```
import 'package:jpaSOAP/pages/pages.dart';
import 'package:jpaSOAP/services/services.dart';
import 'package:jpaSOAP/widgets/widgets.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ClientePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static String routeName = 'cliente';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final directionService = Provider.of<DirectionService>(context);
    final phoneService = Provider.of<PhoneService>(context);
    final clientService = Provider.of<ClientsService>(context);

    //String codigo = clientService.selectedClient.sociedad!.codigo;

    //print(clientService.selectedClient.sociedad!.codigo);

    if (directionService.isLoading) return LoadingScreen();
    if (phoneService.isLoading) return LoadingScreen();

    final _phoneNumber1 = phoneService.phone[0].telefono1!;
    final _phoneNumber2 = phoneService.phone[0].telefono2!;
    final _mail = phoneService.phone[0].correoElectronico!.trim();

    Widget optionOne = SimpleDialogOption(
      child: Text('Direccion: ' +
          directionService.direction[0].nombreVia!.trim() +
          ' ' +
          directionService.direction[0].numeroVia!),
      onPressed: () async {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'mapa');
      },
    );
    Widget optionTwo = SimpleDialogOption(
      child: Text('Localidad: ' + directionService.direction[0].localidad!),
    );
    Widget optionThree = SimpleDialogOption(
      child: Text('Teléfono: ' + phoneService.phone[0].telefono1!),
      onPressed: () async {
        launch('tel://$_phoneNumber1');
      },
    );
    Widget optionFour = SimpleDialogOption(
      child: Text('Teléfono 2: ' + phoneService.phone[0].telefono2!),
      onPressed: () async {
        launch('tel://$_phoneNumber2');
      },
    );
    Widget optionFive = SimpleDialogOption(
      child: Text('Email: ' + phoneService.phone[0].correoElectronico!),
      onPressed: () async {
        launch('mailto:$_mail');
      },
    );

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(63, 63, 156, 1),
          elevation: 0,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'clientes');
                }),
          ],
          title: Text(clientService.selectedClient.nombre! +
              ' ' +
              clientService.selectedClient.apellidos!),
        ),
        drawer: const MenuWidget(),
        body: AppBackground(
          child: SimpleDialog(
            //title: Text(clientService.selectedClient.apellidos!),
            children: [
              optionOne,
              optionTwo,
              optionThree,
              optionFour,
              optionFive,
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Y este es el servicio al que llamo cuando accedo a la pagina de datos del cliente. Pero solo se llama la primera vez que entra, despues si sales y vuelves a entrar ya no pasa por el servicio

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:jpaSOAP/models/models.dart';
import 'package:xml2json/xml2json.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';

class DirectionService extends ChangeNotifier {
  final _baseUrl = Uri.parse('http://xxxx.asmx');
  final _body = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soap12:Body>
          <SociedadDireccion_Lee xmlns="http://xxxx.org/">
            <usuario>xxxx</usuario>
            <password>xxxxxx</password>
            <Codigo>11</Codigo>
          </SociedadDireccion_Lee>
        </soap12:Body>
      </soap12:Envelope>''';

  final List<Direction> direction = [];
  Direction? selectedDirection;

  bool isLoading = true;

  DirectionService() {
    loadDirections();
  }

  Future<List> loadDirections() async {

    this.isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    final resp = await http.post(_baseUrl,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
          "SOAPAction": "http://xxxxx"
        },
        body: _body,
        );

    Xml2Json xml2json = Xml2Json();
    xml2json.parse(resp.body);
    final jsondata = xml2json.toParker();
    final data = json.decode(jsondata);

    final datos = data['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']
        ['SociedadDireccion_LeeResponse']['SociedadDireccion_LeeResult'];

    final directionMap = {'direction': datos};

    directionMap.forEach((key, value) {
      final tempDirection = Direction.fromMap(value);
      tempDirection.codigo = key;
      this.direction.add(tempDirection);
    });

    this.isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();

    return direction;
  }
}
```

Comment: Una aclaración eso es SOAP no REST

Comment: Efectivamente es una peticion SOAP que despues convierto a JSON para que me devuelva los datos en modo JSON